# CSS: horizontally overflow a table

Tags: html, css, overflow, css-tables

The question is: There is some HTML automatically generated by other people which I can't modify. And I'm asked to write a stylesheet to fix table display. The `<table>` element is contained in a `<div>` element. If the `<table>` is wider than the `<div>` element, then it will overflow. The easiest way to fix this is to add `overflow-x: scroll` to the `<div>` element. However, there are also other elements in the `<div>` element and this will also scroll those elements. So this method is not acceptable.

The best solution I have right now is to force the table display as a block element using `display: block` on the `<table>` element. Then adding `overflow-x: scroll` on the `<table>` element seems to fix the overflow problem. But another problem occurs with this method: When the `<table>` doesn't have enough cells, it would still go full width (because it displays as a block element). This makes terrible borders.

So how can I correctly overflow the table when there are many cells, and correctly display its border when there are only a few cells?

[jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/kbvfnm1x/27/)

Comment: you can your below property as i mention or let me know if dont want to use height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No problem. I found the answer:

```
.mytable {
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

[CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/VBPmEB)

Answer (score 0):

You can use below properties  ::

```
overflow: auto; height:100px;
```